# How can i enable Collection Balancing only between two specific shards in mongoDB which containing more than 2 shards

Tags: mongodb, sharding

Let say i have shards- shard0000,shard0001,shard0002,shard0004

now i want to store some type of data only on shard- shard0000 and shard0003 and want to enable balancing between them.
my other shards too store same type of data but they are based on some range and i don't want to enable balancing for them.

Comment: What do you mean by "type of data"? Same data, different collection?

Comment: yes means same type of document in same collection

Comment: So I get that right: You have one collection on 4 different shards and only want to have this collection balanced between of those shards? Could you explain the idea behind that`Because we have to find another solution to your problem if the above is correct.

Comment: i have products document and i want to store these products on different shard based on its category for that i have defined 4 shards now my 2 shards store products of same category and 2 stores products of other category.Now  i want to balance the shard which stores products of same category leaving other shards unbalanced.my shards have tags and tagranges too.

Comment: Ok, and why would you want some shards unbalanced?

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use [tag aware sharding](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/tag-aware-sharding/) - essentially you tag the shard key ranges (it must be based on the shard key) to specify what shards you wish to have that data live on.

For example, you could say that shard0000 and shard0003 are "shard-set1" by [tagging them](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/administer-shard-tags/) as such.  You would then determine what ranges of data belong on that set and [tag those ranges](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/administer-shard-tags/#tag-a-shard-key-range) appropriately.  The balancer will then respect those tags and move data accordingly, as well as balance the chunks within the tagged set.

Comment: thanks for your reply.. but in that case i have to enable balancing on that collection which cause movement of chunks from one shard to another.But i want only balancing between specific shards leaving other shards of same collection un balanced.

Comment: i have also used tag based sharding which stores data based on tag range.but i don't want to balance data between two different shard tags.i want to only balance data between same shard tags.. and i don't know how to do it.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding what is happening - the tagged chunks are only balanced between tagged shards.  The only reason for movement between tags is if data that should be on a tag has been put elsewhere (for example when you set up tags first, or if you change the tag ranges).

Comment: If you (for example) have a collection on shard1 unsharded, then you shard it and tag it such that all ranges describing its data will live on shard2 and shard 3, then all data must be moved from shard1 to the other 2 shards (and balanced between them).  Once that initial move is done, then data will only be balanced between shard2 and shard3.

Comment: thanks Adam i got you ..i think i am misunderstanding the concept.let me check it.